# PCC-S-02201 : Pro*C does not allow [LONG VARCHAR] type

Tags: c++, c, oracle, proc

in my Pro*C program :

Although oracle doc is suggesting to use LONG VARCHAR instead of VARCHAR whenever we want to exceed 65500 bytes, Pro*C compiler does not accept the key-word [LONG VARCHAR].

```
LONG VARCHAR versements[LONG_VERS];
```

Answer (score 0):

`LONG VARCHAR` is an External Datatype.  See [Table 3-4 here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/api/doc/PC_22/ch03a.htm#dev-t-ext_dty)

How to use external datatypes is discussed in more [detail here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/fcdb/oracle/or-proc.html).  Following is an excerpt:

> Oracle recognizes two kinds of datatypes: internal and external.
> Internal datatypes specify how Oracle stores column values in database
> tables. External datatypes specify the formats used to store values in
> input and output host variables. At precompile time, a default Oracle
> external datatype is assigned to each host variable. Datatype
> equivalencing allows you to override this default equivalencing and
> lets you control the way Oracle interprets the input data and formats
> the output data.
>
> The equivalencing can be done on a variable-by-variable basis using
> the VAR statement. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> EXEC SQL VAR <host_var> IS <type_name> [ (<length>) ];
> ```
>
> ... You can also equivalence user-defined datatypes to Oracle external
> datatypes using the TYPE statement. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> EXEC SQL TYPE <user_type> IS <type_name> [ (<length>) ] [REFERENCE];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked for me :

```
typedef struct
{
    long len;
    char arr[1036810];
} long_varchar;

long_varchar versements;

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
EXEC SQL type long_varchar is LONG VARCHAR (1036810);
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```